# CharField filenames into ImageFields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=240)
```

And a corresponding MySQL table, filled with filenames (copied from an existing table).

In the future I may want to upload new photos to the model via admin. Is it possible to evolve the current model into something with ImageFields and integrate my legacy data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, assuming the current `filename` field in your model contains the full path to the actual file, you can add a new field (ImageField) to your model and migrate it using South, then write a script to update your data.

A skeleton example,

```
from django.core.files import File

# assuming your updated model looks like:
# class Photo(models.Model):
#     filename = models.CharField(max_length=240)
#     image = models.ImageField(max_length=240)

photos = Photo.objects.all()
for p in photos:
    f = open(p.filename)
    myimage = File(f)
    p.image.save(image_name, myimage) # name, content
```

And then remove the old `filename` field via South. Take a look at Django's `FileField` first for more information, since `ImageField` essentially inherits all of the former's attribute and methods. (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField)